# Setting the values of a combo box dynamically on an Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to dynamically set the value of one combo boxbased on the selection of another. Every time I run this is says object variable or with block variable not set

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmbReport_AfterUpdate()
    'Gets the Report
    If cmbReport = "Audit type" Then
        Set Data = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "SELECT AuditTypeName  FROM tblAuditType")
    End If

    Set rs = Data.OpenRecordset

    'Sets the data
    With Me.cmbData
        .Recordset = rs
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If cmdData is a combo box, it should be `.Rowsource` not `.Recordset`

```
Private Sub cmbReport_AfterUpdate()
    If cmbReport = "Audit type" Then
        cmbData.Rowsource = "SELECT AuditTypeName FROM tblAuditType"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly - there's no need to create a QueryDef.